# Get list values by index

Tags: c#, linq, list

i have a list filled with tables from my db, i gave each table a number, and now i want 
to open the table and show all its values based on the number chosen by the user.

**code**:

```
   List<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable> tables = db.Mapping.GetTables().ToList();



            for (int i = 0; i < tables.Count(); i++)
            {
                var s = tables[i].TableName;
                Console.WriteLine(i+". "+s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Choose value to open");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(str);

            List<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable> query =
            from t in tables[number].TableName
            select t; <--- stuck here :*(
        } } }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What are you trying to select out of `tables[number].` ?, `TableName` is just a string so you query is just returning a `IEnumerable<char>` not `List<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable>`

Answer (score 1):

if you want each value on a new line, presuming your data's ToString output is acceptable

```
Console.Write(tables[number].Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, b) => a + Environment.NewLine + b))
```

Comment: in what way is it not working? does it not compile? does it error?...console.writeline within the query isn't really the right place to do things, microsoft omitted the foreach(do stuff) equivalent from linq because you shouldn't be calling things with side effects in a query